# Почему вылетает ошибка "no such tablel"?

Tags: python, django

При попытке сохранения модели вылетает ошибка no such table: account_character_model, бд - sqlLite код:

```
character_form = forms.Character_form(request.POST,request.FILES)
    if not character_form:
        print("not form")
        return redirect('/createChar')
    if not character_form.is_valid():
        print('not valid')
        return redirect('/createChar')

    character = character_form.save(commit=False)
    for field in character.__dict__.keys():
        if field in character_form.cleaned_data:
            setattr(character,field,character_form.cleaned_data[field])
    character.user = request.user
    if 'character_image' in request.FILES:
        character.character_image = request.FILES['character_image']
    else:
        character.character_image = "personages/personages_picts/standart.jpg"
    character.save()
```

Comment: Нет такой таблицы в бд? Миграции делали?

Comment: К сожелению делал : (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я действительно забыл сделать повторную миграцию ^_^